# Can Azure FrontDoor private link connect to another subscription

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-front-door

i am trying to connect a private link between az FD in sub1 to az Storage blob in sub2.

I am unsure how this can be achieved, most documents have indicated to create private link from destination and provide a private link service to source, but in the case of AZ Frontdoor premium, a privatelink from SAAS is created to the target. Perhaps I need to grant the source sub Network Contributor role to the target sub but not sure how this can be accomplish.

This can be done if the FD and Storage is in the same subscription. Im not sure if this is possible if 2 subscriptions are under the same Resource Management Group, that would be great to know as well but my test above involves 2 different tenants.

When i tried this through the cli using az afd origin create cmd([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/standard-premium/how-to-enable-private-link-storage-account-cli#enable-private-link-to-a-storage-account-in-azure-front-door-premium)) I get this error:

```
Code: LinkedAuthorizationFailed
Message: The client has permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/read' on scope '/subscriptions/sub1/resourceGroups/xx/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/test-frontdoor/originGroups/testCrossSubOrigin/origins/mystorageorigin', however the current tenant 'sub1' is not authorized to access linked subscription 'sub2'.
```

I've tried adding the src tenant to target's tenant "Cross-tenant access settings" in AD but no luck or it didn't seem to do anything.